# WebClient download images in sequence causes issue with ImageList

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, controls, webclient

I have spent a far bit of days getting into VB.NET and getting a program surprisingly fairly connected via MySQL & verifies bcrypt hashes via login dialog. All works so wonderfully.

When a user proceeds to `Form2`, we have this code to work the list from MySQL results:

```
Dim transferstable As New DataTable

sql = "SQL-SELECT-QUERY"

With cmd
    .Connection = con
    .CommandText = sql
End With
For Each row As DataRow In transferstable.Rows
    Using client As New WebClient()
        Dim Url = "domain.org/images/covers/" & row.Item("cover")
        client.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(Url), "C:\\App_Uploads\" & row.Item("cover"))
    End Using
Next
For Each row As DataRow In transferstable.Rows
    ' myImage barely loading image for each row, usually first 2 rows out of ~160 rows
    Dim myImage As System.Drawing.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\App_Uploads\" & row.Item("cover"))
    ListControl1.Add("somename", "item title", "description", "sideinfo", myImage, 1)
Next
```

So the first block works fine, it downloads ALL of the images to `C:\\App_Uploads`

However we **can not properly pass these images to ListControl1.Add()** without it giving up / running out of memory.

Using a fixed local image like `C:\\test.png` works fine and assigns to every single row in the list (all 160 rows) found from database, but how can we assign our offline (downloaded) images to the results? It is just wracking our brain on many hours now.

We got this far! thanks!

**Result with images iterated locally per row**:

[image: Unexpected results]

**Result with local image iterated per row**:

```
Dim myImage As System.Drawing.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\test.png")
```

[image]

**UPDATE ---**

We removed For Each from wrapping WebClient() and seem to be in the right direction, however only 1-2 images load into view.

```
' Download image art locally            
Using client As New WebClient()
    Dim Url = "domain.com/images/covers/" & transferstable.Rows(0).Item(14)
    Await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(New Uri(Url), "C:\\App_Uploads\" & transferstable.Rows(0).Item(14))
End Using

For Each row As DataRow In transferstable.Rows
    Dim myImage As System.Drawing.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\App_Uploads\" & row.Item("cover"))
    ListControl1.Add("somename", "item title", "description", "sideinfo", myImage, 1)
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're downloading Images in a loop using the event-driven (non-awaitable) version of WebClient's `DownloadFile()`, [DownloadFileAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfileasync). The WebClient object is declared in with a `Using` statement.
Assuming that the WebClient instance can terminate the download before it's disposed, the `DownloadFileAsync()` method returns immediately: you're supposed to subscribe to the [DownloadFileCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfilecompleted) to receive a notification when the file is ready.

After this first loop completes, another loop is started, to retrieve the images from the disk.
Again assuming that all files are actually downloaded (I haven't tested it), you have a race condition, since you're trying to immediately use files that may not be completed or that are not actually there (and possibly never will be).

It's probably preferable, in this context, to download all the images in parallel, without storing them on disk, unless strictly required; only after the download is complete for sure, present the images in the UI.

---

An example of an alternative method that makes use of a static (`Shared`) [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient) object declared in a helper class that exposes a public method, `DownloadImages()`, which is responsible for returning an *ordered* `List(Of Image)`.
The HttpClient object is declared as `Lazy(Of HttpClient)` here.
See the documentation about the [Lazy<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1) class for more information.
(if you don't like it, you can probably change/remove the `Lazy<T>` instantiation here).

The order of the Images in the List depends on the order in which the download URLs are passed to the method: the images are returned in the same order.
The `DownloadImages()` method generates a numeric sequence, which is passed, along with the URL, to the private `GetImage()` method:

```
Dim tasks = urlList.Select(Function(url, idx) GetImage(idx, New Uri(url)))
```

The sequence is added because awating [Task.WhenAll()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall) doesn't guarantee that the Tasks are returned in a specific order.
The `List(Of Task)` is then reordered using the original sequence, in case the order is a matter of importance in your use case.

**Note**: the Images are downloaded in parallel. If you download a lot of images from the same address or quite frequently, your IP Address may end up in a *black list*.

To use the class, create a new `DownloadImagesHelper` object and a collection of Urls (as strings).
Then await the call to the `DownloadImages()` method.
When the method returns, loop the list of Images you get back and add new Items to your Control.
For example:

```
Dim urls As New List(Of String) 
For Each row As DataRow In transferstable.Rows
    urls.Add($"domain.org/images/covers/{row.Item("cover")}") 
Next

Dim downloadHelper = New DownloadImagesHelper()
Dim images = Await downloadHelper.DownloadImages(urls)

For Each img As Image In images
   ListControl1.Add("somename", "item title", "description", "sideinfo", img, 1)
Next
```

The class implements [IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable). Call its `Dispose()` method when you're done with the `DownloadImagesHelper` object. The Dispose method *tries to* (it's not immediate) close existing connections and dispose of the HttpClient.

**Helper class**:

Note: the `DownloadImages()` doesn't check the status of the returned Tasks:

```
Return tasks.OrderBy(Function(t) t.Result.Key).Select(Function(t) t.Result.Value)
```

You may verify in different conditions whether it's preferable to add this check, as in:

```
Return tasks.Where(Function(t) t.Status = TaskStatus.RanToCompletion).
             OrderBy(Function(t) t.Result.Key).
             Select(Function(t) t.Result.Value)
```

In case you don't want to return a result when an Image could not be downloaded because of some HTTP exception, set the Image value to `Nothing` in `GetImage()` (described in code) and filter the results in `DownloadImages()`:

```
Return tasks.OrderBy(Function(t) t.Result.Key).
             Where(Function(t) t.Result.Value IsNot Nothing).
             Select(Function(t) t.Result.Value)
```

Or just return the null results and filter later, in the code that called these methods.

---

Note: The HttpClientHandler is initialized setting its [SslProtocols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.sslprotocols) property.
This requires at least .Net Framework 4.8, otherwise it doesn't do anything (the Docs say .Net Framework 4.7.2+, don't believe it :)
Also, the property is hard-coded to `SslProtocols.Tls12` (it's there to present the matter). You could remove it or set it to `SslProtocols.Default`, or add, e.g., `SslProtocols.Tls11` in case the default System setting (usually TLS12) is not supported by one or more servers you're downloading from.
`SslProtocols.Tls13`, even though it's included, currently cannot be used, so don't add it.
If you're using an older .Net version, you need to set the TLS version using the [ServicePointManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager) directly, **before** you create any connection.   For example:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

---

**EDIT:**
Changed the return Type of `DownloadImages()` to `Task(Of List(Of Image))` instead of `Task(Of IEnumerable(Of Image))`, since it may be simpler to debug and handle locally. Change it back if you need a deferred execution.

Added a `DummyImage` Property that can be set to a dummy Bitmap, to set in case the HTTP request generates an exception (404 and similar).

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Security.Authentication
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Public Class DownloadImagesHelper
    Implements IDisposable

    Private Shared ReadOnly client As New Lazy(Of HttpClient)(
        Function()
            Dim handler As New HttpClientHandler() With {
                .SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12,
                .AllowAutoRedirect = True,
                .AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
                .CookieContainer = New CookieContainer()
            }
            Dim client As New HttpClient(handler)
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = False
            Return client
        End Function)

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Property DummyImage As Image = Nothing

    Public Async Function DownloadImages(urlList As IEnumerable(Of String)) As Task(Of List(Of Image))
        Dim tasks = urlList.Select(Function(url, idx) GetImage(idx, New Uri(url)))
        Await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(False)
        Return tasks.OrderBy(Function(t) t.Result.Key).Select(Function(t) t.Result.Value).ToList()
        ' Or, depending what you have decided to do in GetImage()
        ' only return results that have a non-null Image
        ' Return tasks.OrderBy(Function(t) t.Result.Key).Where(Function(t) t.Result.Value IsNot Nothing).Select(Function(t) t.Result.Value).ToList()
    End Function

    Private Async Function GetImage(pos As Integer, url As Uri) As Task(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Image))
        Dim imageData As Byte() = Nothing
        Try
            imageData = Await client.Value.GetByteArrayAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(False)
            Return New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Image)(
            pos, DirectCast(New ImageConverter().ConvertFrom(imageData), Image)
        )
        Catch hrEx As HttpRequestException
            ' Or return a null Image: Return New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Image)(pos, Nothing)
            Return New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Image)(pos, DummyImage)
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        Dispose(True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub
    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        client?.Value?.CancelPendingRequests()
        client?.Value?.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I appreciate that so much - I have have read throughly and implemented accordingly. However we are at a ton of syntax errors in the class and have to convert Private Share Readonly client is causing a ton of problems, not dependencies. We converted it to be VB,NET compatible as its C# I think, is that correct? how come it fails validation? added as a class file

Comment: Private Shared ReadOnly client As New Lazy(Of HttpClient)(
Function()
Using handler As New HttpClientHandler
 With handler
 .SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12
 .AllowAutoRedirect = True
.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip
.CookieContainer = New CookieContainer()
End With
Dim client As New HttpClient(handler)
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = False
Return client
End Using
End Function)

Comment: No, this is VB.Net 15, standard declaration syntax, with a Lambda Function.  You need VB.Net 15+. If you have an older version of the language or .Net, you need to you need to specify it in the question -- **DO NOT** declare the `HttpClientHandler` with a `Using` statement: this is not meant to be disposed of. Use the public `Dispose()` method that the `DownloadImagesHelper` class provides.

Comment: Actually, I've tested `<LangVersion>12</LangVersion>` and it's still compatible. This: `client?.Value?.Dispose()` would fail first, if you had an older version. You must have copied or formatted it wrong. Don't change `With { ... }`: this is very standard VB.Net syntax. `With ... End With` it's a different thing used for something else.

Comment: I copied the class exactly as shown and inserted into a new class file in project tree (we updated it when we had no validation no matter what), Visual Studio 2019. I should of been more exact on my OP, but that being said the class should pass parsing if I have the latest studio edition. Will mark answered when class works for me in my IDE, everything else validated perfectly fine

Comment: Well, this works without any issue in VS 2019 (VB.Net 16 -> 16.9), pasted in as-is. I hope you added to the class all the `Imports` specified. -- It would be better to explicitly define the Language version, in case you have migrated the Solution from a previous version of VS. -- BTW, you still haven't described what kind of GUI Platform you're using. You need to do that: those `.ConfigureAwait(False)` may work in different ways in different GUI platforms.

Comment: We did migrate from a previous solution on a earlier VS version, I wonder if that is why. I can try defining the target version as you posted <LangVersion>
Imports are correct, no issues there - it even removed unneeded import references but I keep them anyway. For GUI, I really don’t know.. We are using this - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/333864/Flexible-List-Control

Comment: So, the GUI Platform is WinForms. What .Net version? -- If you're using .Net Framework, open up each Project's `.vbproj` file and add   `<PropertyGroup<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion></PropertyGroup>` before all other 
`<PropertyGroup>` nodes. Check beforehand whether you already have that option set to something else in any Project.

Comment: I am using .NET Core (I believe) and is 4.6.1 x64 - perfect I will check that right away!

Comment: `4.6.1` is a .Net Framework version (old) `.Net Core` stopped at `3.1` (now in extended support), next is `.Net`, starting from `5.0`, now in `6.0 preview`. But it doesn't matter, .Net 4.6.1 has support for all that's in here.

Comment: now at .NET 4.8 & project target updated, I got the class working fully right from copy paste no modifications, now the loop is still not adding images in, I take the control and place as standalone (removing the loops and the code provided) and have a dummy image in the list, so no list at all with the examples provided. I got this far, strange!

Comment: Using the code here, all images are loaded before you used them, so, if some image is not shown, it wasn't downloaded, the format is not compatible or nothing was returned. The `DownloadImages()` returns a collection of Images. Add `.ToList()` to the result, set a breakpoint there and inspect the content of the `List(Of Image)`, see what you got. -- As suggested, try to change to `Return tasks.Where(Function(t) t.Status = TaskStatus.RanToCompletion).OrderBy(Function(t) t.Result.Key).Select(Function(t) t.Result.Value)` the return value of the method, see how many Images are actually returned.

Comment: Your absolutely correct I just noticed that myself, it was a protocol issue and Tls12 is the answer. Then I moved  Dim urls As New List(Of String)  right after Form2_Load and that got it working. So now I get a response once Form2 loads from a message box "Response status code does not indicate a success: 404 (Not Found)." - that says it must be all in order and it is up to my resource to be correct! That's amazing man, so close!

Comment: I have my first image! By setting the SQL query to LIMIT 1, I have a picture right away. That's perfect! It is not loading more than 1 image and rarely the image link will not resolve as they don't have media, how can I skip a unresolved request to a non-existent image? Or does it handle that on its own?

Comment: I've changed the code a bit, to catch a `HttpRequestException`, which will return either the value of the new `DummyImage` property or `Nothing`. -- Read the notes I've added, in the body of the answer, in the **EDIT** part and in code. Make sure to make all the changes described and decide whether you want to return a null Image or a dummy Image; also, as described, when to filter the null Images, if you opt for that solution.

Comment: Working  ***perfectly!!!*** Thank you so much, the last changes did the trick! We have a full list of unique images and all is very stable, we can now assign a dummy image to the bitmap call. Amazing man.