# How to pass Value from Last Loop?

Tags: vb.net, loops, graphics, concatenation

I have been attempting many ways to retrieve 2 collections together, while the first collection holds a comma-separated value in a column, we can not find a solution to passing the first collection value to the second `For Each`.

This code simply retrieves database rows and adds each result to our list control using the `Add()` method.

```
Dim transferstable As New DataTable

count = 0
For Each row As DataRow In transferstable.Rows
    Dim name = Truncate(row.Item("name"), 42)
    ListControl1.Add(name, row.Item("username")", row.Item("added"), avatars, row.Item("online"), images(count), 0)
    count += 1
Next
```

**Problem**

We need to nest the loops, so we get the value from the first collection from the "avatars" column (image1,image2,image3) and call it from Add() - 4th parameter.

We only get always 1 string result into the view, while the actual query reports many rows with 2 strings (image1, image2) so I tried this:

```
Dim lst As New List(Of String) From {
                transferstable.Rows(0).Item(8)
            }
            count = 0
            For Each item As String In lst

                For Each row As DataRow In transferstable.Rows
                    Dim name = Truncate(row.Item("name"), 42)
                    ListControl1.Add(name, row.Item("username")", row.Item("added"), item, row.Item("online"), images(count), 0)
                    count += 1
                Next

            Next
```

And the still the same single result! (8) is the GROUP_CONCAT column for "avatars" How do we pass this list over to the 4th parameter?

We want to retrieve these as URL remote images and render them to view with Bitmap.

**Expected result**:
A list of 15x15 pictures that represent each split result from GROUP_CONCAT(avatars)

I've been at all different ways to do this for most of the day, I know nesting is the right direction but I can't figure out why only **1** result is coming back (image1  -  not image1,image2, etc.)

Some physical image files do not exist anymore, so rendering that to view also has it halt after a few single string results, so it quits and gives an error, like a 404 but does not proceed with the 180 other rows.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-each-next-statement

Comment: Do you mean that Column(8) contains a list of names representing images and each `username` can have multiple associated images (possibly a different number)? If so, you need to loop the Rows first, for each Row get the value of Column(8) and split its content on the separator, then loop this new collection and add to the Control the `username` in the current Row + each image in the list (plus the other stuff). If you have implemented [the code posted yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69111511/7444103), you won't have any Http exception. Get the images in the same loop, add what you got.

Comment: What is Truncate? `Math.Truncate` takes a single parameter, a `Decimal` or `Double`.

Comment: Hi Jimi, thank you for responding! Your previous solution is 100% implemented and working wonderfully. I was so curious about adopting your solution toward the (split avatar filenames), or the 8th column. I will give it a strong go reflecting the code you shared prior, and I will try to resolve the avatars with Split() and iterate a row of pictures display per each row, I will be grateful.

Comment: `ListControl1.Add(name, row.Item("username")", row.Item("added"), avatars, row.Item("online"), images(count), 0)` has odd number double quotes. That is no going to work.

Comment: @Mary - It is a custom function I found on a online forum, as there is no native split support. It works fine on any string, from 2 to 4, any INT value. I was not aware of that however, thank you. You are correct, that is just a edit for the post, not the live code. I'll update post.

Comment: Okay, so what is Truncate doing. String.Split is natively available in vb.net via the .net Framework.

Comment: Public Function Truncate(value As String, length As Integer) As String
        ' If argument is too big, return the original string.
        ' Otherwise take a substring from the string's start index.
        If length > value.Length Then
            Return value
        Else
            Return value.Substring(0, length)
        End If
    End Function

Comment: Have a look at Substring. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-5.0

Comment: What is the purpose of `count`? If you want to know the number of rows `transferstable.Rows.Count`

Comment: count was the only way we could ever begin to actually loop the rows, thank you I didn't know that! :D

Comment: `Dim lst As New List(Of String) From {transferstable.Rows(0)(8).ToString()}` Will give you a list with a single item. I added the .ToString so it would compile with Option Strict on which should always be on.

Comment: I think you want something like `Dim lst = (From row As DataRow In dt.AsEnumerable Select row.Field(Of String)(8)).ToList`

Comment: @jimi - I did as you suggested - and I have nothing but "Value of type 'List(Of Image)' can not be convert to 'String'." I added the second line in the For Each under the urls ```var avatars.Add("example.com/" & row.Item("avatars"))``` reflecting exactly as done for the other images.

Comment: Still no luck pulling up row of images per row (row(8)) this is what I came up with, ```For Each row As DataRow In transferstable.Rows
                Dim value = row.Item("avatars")
                Dim SplitList = Split(value, ",")
                avatars.Add("domain.com/" & SplitList)
            Next``` maybe im not understanding the first comment